# GridView Paging, Controls not working in Google Chrome or Safari?

Tags: gridview, safari, google-chrome, updatepanel

I have a gridview within an updatepanel which allows paging and has a linkbutton that when clicked shows a modalpopup for editing records. This works fine in IE, Firefox, and Opera but I do not get a postback in Chrome or Safari?? I have other linkbuttons on the page that are within updatepanels but are not within gridviews that are working fine. I have scowered the web but cannot find a solution. Part of my code is below, anyone have any ideas??

```
#

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upReports" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">  
    #             <ContentTemplate>  
    #             <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMachID" runat="server" />  
    #             <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewLead" runat="server" Value="no" />  
    #             <div class="fullWidth">  
    #                 <div class="heading">  
    #                     <h2 style="padding:10px">  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblResults" runat="server" />  
    #                     </h2>  
    #                 </div>  
    #                   
    #                 <!-- Machine Leads -->  
    #                 <asp:GridView ID="gvMachLeads" runat="server" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
    #                      GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="true"  
    #                      OnPageIndexChanging="gvMachLeads_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"   
    #                      onrowcommand="gvMachLeads_RowCommand" PageSize="15">  
    #                     <Columns>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateC") %>'   
    #                              CssClass="repGridText" ToolTip='<%# "Origin: " + Eval("LeadOrigin") %>' />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LeadStatus") %>'   
    #                              CssClass="repGridText" ToolTip='<%# "Notes: " + Eval("Comments") %>' />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblCustomer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'   
    #                              CssClass="repGridText" ToolTip='<%# "Address: " + Eval("Add1") + " - " + Eval("City") +   
    #                              " - " + Eval("State") + " - " + Eval("Zip") %>' />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phone") %>'   
    #                              ToolTip='<%# "Contact: " + Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName") %>'    
    #                              CssClass="repGridText" />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'  
    #                              CssClass="repGridLbtn" NavigateUrl='<%#"mailto:" + Eval("Email") %>' />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ESM" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblRsm" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EsmTerritory") %>'   
    #                              ToolTip='<%# "Agent: " + Eval("AgentName") + ", Salesperson: " + Eval("SalesPerson") %>'  
    #                              CssClass="repGridText" />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnMach" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MachModel") %>'   
    #                              CssClass="repGridLbtn" CommandName="GetMachInfo"   
    #                              ToolTip='<%# "Factory: " + Eval("Producer") %>'   
    #                              CommandArgument=<%# Eval("MachID") + "§" + Eval("Name") + "<br />" + Eval("MachModel") %> />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Est. Sales" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
    #                     <ItemTemplate>  
    #                         <asp:Label ID="lblEstSales" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("EstSales"))%>'   
    #                              ToolTip='<%# "Invoice Probability: " +  Eval("InvProb") + "%, Chance: " +   
    #                              Eval("Chance") + "%" %>' CssClass="repGridText" />  
    #                     </ItemTemplate>  
    #                     </asp:TemplateField>  
    #                     </Columns>  
    #                 </asp:GridView>  
    #             </div>  
    #             </ContentTemplate>  
    #             </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the link below.
http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/Gotcha-WebKit-%28Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome%29-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If grid view is working fine (I mean visible properly) on IE, Firefox, and Opera, but not in Google chrome, then do the necessary changes into your code:
add `visible="false"` in your `<asp:UpdateProgress>` tag.